# Allow custom value in @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

Is there an option to allow a user to enter their own value into a @Html.DropDownListFor?

I tried making it content editable but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can add with javascript like below:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){    
    var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>')
            .val($('#txtval').val())
                .html($('#txtname').val()));
});
```